# Присвоил массиву Button id, как теперь обратиться к конкретной кнопке?

Tags: java, android

Есть массив Button, присвоил каждой кнопке id.
Но как теперь обратиться по этому id?

---

```
while (i < 10){
    face.numButtonFace[i].setText(face.but[i]);
    face.numButtonFace[i].setId(View.generateViewId());
    i++;
}
```

---

---

Дело в том что при повторной загрузке страницы id снова меняется

Comment: Да без разницы, в массиве 10 кнопок. это подойдет только к 1 кнопке, но не к массиву

Comment: Что вам нужно сделать с этими id?

Comment: Передать в метод Onclick, конкретное в оператор switch

Comment: "Дело в том что при повторной загрузке страницы id снова меняется". потому что у вас $i = 0 в коде написано (скорее всего). вот оно и сбрасывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(face.numButtonFace[i].getId());
```

Comment: в while так не прокатит, только последняя кнопка будет дублирована

Comment: Почему бы не использовать цикл `for` ?

Comment: Вы спросили как обратиться, вот вам пример обращения. Ставьте любую цифру заместо i.